# Generate a QR-code to log into Wireless (wifi) with WPA encryption

Tags: linux, security, wifi, wpa, qr-code

I installed a command-line QR-code generator:

```
apt install qrencode
```

I used the following format, so the QR scanner knows what to do with the content:

```
WIFI:T:WPA;S:<your Wi-Fi network name>;P:<your Wi-Fi network password>;;
```

generating the QR image file then works like this:

```
qrencode "WIFI:T:WPA;S:My_Network;P:My_very_secure_Password;;" -o wifi_login.png
```

this generates an image file `wifi_login.png` with the QR encoded string.

while the option `-o FILENAME` or `--output=FILENAME` makes `qrencode` write the generated image to this `FILENAME`. `-` can be used to print to standard output.

The whole procedure works pretty well with MAC devices, but not with Android.

**Is there anything wrong with the string, making it not Android-compatible?**

Comment: does your android device scan other qr codes properly? do your SSID contain special characters like `\`, `;`, `,` or `:`? could either be interpreted as a hexadecimal number?

Comment: @Fox the Android QR-scanner from Kaspersky reads the QR code correctly, but does not seem to pass it in the right way to the Network Login Interface. When I copy the Password manually from the QR-scanner to the Login Interface it works. So the format of my string seems to be correct.

Comment: sounds like a permission-issue or a feature missing from the app then rather than a QR problem imo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command line work properly , special characters are allowed in the SSID (doesn't need to be escaped) but in the password it should be escaped.